# Automatic integration tests between client and API

Tags: ios, json, api, testing, integration-testing

im currently developing an iOS application that communicates with a JSON API.

Im in the process of building a test suite for integration tests between client and server, basically test all the endpoints.

How devs normally do this? How do you delete objects in the server between tests cases? Do you have a testing interface for the client?

What strategy would you recommend?

Thanks before hand.

Answer (score 1):

For testing my client interaction with a server I have used OCMock http://ocmock.org

All the client communications goes through a central wrapper class around NSURLConnection and by creating a mock of this class it is straightforward for test code to emulate server functionality - response to client requests, reply with HTTP responses, JSON payloads etc. etc. depending upon what you want to test.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Im trying to integrate the client with the server so mocking is not an option. Any other suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean by integrate? And in your original question you ask how to delete objects in the server. You are talking about testing the client on the device and a server somewhere else that the device communicates with aren't you? I'm not aware of any tools that would permit such testing, it would be a vastly ambitious tool if it exists. I'll be interested to see if anybody replies with such a testing tool/infrastructure.

Comment: What a mean by integrating is making real API calls, not making them. The problem i have with this tests is that i need to know the state of the server before and after running every single case.

One posible solution could be to have a special endpoints on the server for dropping the database before running any test case.

Comment: I have issue similar like bilby91, I also want to add integration test for multi-request API.
Ex: I have 5 API, I want to call sequence each API, in response successful of the first API, I want to call next API.
What tool/framework can help me?
@bilby91, do you find solution?

Comment: @TranTrungHieu I ended up mocking the responses for test, it was not worth the effort. What type of integration test you are trying to achieve ? You own the 5 APIs ? Probably will be too much trouble for the benefits you are going to get out of it.

Comment: Yes, i also mock response data by using Nocilla and finish writing UTs for each API. Next, i want to implement integration test in Xcode, similar as [Soap-UI](https://www.soapui.org) tool.
I just study KIF framework, but it so big.